# c how to make a dynamic array pointer in a struct

Tags: c, arrays, struct

I am taking in input from the user for the number of elemenets inside an array.  The array is inside my struct 'Polymer'

```
struct Polymer
{
    int length;

    struct Monomer *monomer;

}polymer;
```

In main, I am creating a new monomer array pointer and setting the mononomer pointer in "Polymer" to it

```
struct Monomer *monomers[size];
polymer.monomer = momomers;
```

I am getting the error "Assignment from incompatible pointer type" which I assume is because we are converting a monomer array pointer to a monomer.  How do I declare it as a monomer array pointer in the struct?

Comment: Also, you should use `size_t` for array sizes, string lengths, and anything else with a size. `int` is signed (you don't want an array of -1 length, do you?) and is not guaranteed to be large enough to properly store a size (or, in the pathological case, it might be too large).

Answer (score 5):

You are declaring an **array of monomer pointers** when you probably want an **array of monomers**. Drop the `*`:

```
struct Monomer monomers[size];
polymer.monomer = momomers;
```

Answer (score 2):

```
struct Monomer *monomers[size];
polymer.monomer = momomers;
```

`monomers` is an **array of pointers**. They aren't pointing to any valid locations and has garbage values. While `Polymer::monomer` is a **pointer**. Array of pointers isn't type compatible to just a pointer.

Instead try -

```
struct Monomer monomers[size];
polymer.monomer = momomers;  // 2
```

Now this statement 2 is valid because array decays to a pointer.

Comment: This isn't C++, shouldn't it be Polymer.monomer?

Comment: @BlackBear - Technically to say, `.` operator should be associated with an **object**. Here `Polymer` is the struct name. So, to say it's member I just used the operator `::`.